# Cassandra - secondary index and query performance

Tags: sql, cassandra, query-performance, database, nosql

my schema for the table is : 
**A)**

```
CREATE TABLE friend_list (
    userId uuid,
    friendId uuid,
    accepted boolean, 
    ts_accepted timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((userId ,accepted), ts_accepted)
   ) with clustering order by (ts_accepted desc);
```

Here I am able to perform queries like:

```
1.  SELECT * FROM friend_list WHERE userId="---" AND accepted=true;
2.  SELECT * FROM friend_list WHERE userId="---" AND accepted=false;
3.  SELECT * FROM friend_list WHERE userId="---" AND accepted IN (true,false);
```

But the 3rd query involves more read, so I tried to change the schema like this :

**B)**

```
 CREATE TABLE friend_list (
        userId uuid,
        friendId uuid,
        accepted boolean, 
        ts_accepted timestamp,
        PRIMARY KEY (userId , ts_accepted)
       ) with clustering order by (ts_accepted desc);
CREATE INDEX ON friend_list (accepted);
```

With this type B schema, the 1st and 2nd queries works, but I can simplify the third query as :

```
3. SELECT * FROM friend_list WHERE userId="---";
```

I believe that the second schema gives much better performance for third query, as it won't do the condition check on every row.

Cassandra experts...Please suggest me which is the best schema on achieving this.A or B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , are you aware that your second schema does not work at all like the first one ? In the first one the 'accepted' field was part of the key, but in the second not at all ! You don't have the same unique constraint, you should check that it is not a problem for your model.

Second if you only want to not have to include the 'acceptation' field for every request you have two possibilities :

1 - You can use 'acceptation' as a clustering column :

```
PRIMARY KEY ((userId), accepted, ts_accepted)
```

This way your 3rd request can be :

```
SELECT * FROM friend_list WHERE userId="---";
```

And you will get the same result more efficiently.

But this approach has a problem, it will create larger partitions, which is not the best for good performances.

2 - Create two separate tables

This approach is much more adequate for the Cassandra spirit. With Cassandra it is not unusual to duplicate the data if it can improve the efficiency of the requests.

So in your case you would keep your first schema for the first table and the first and second request,

and you would create another table with the same data but a schema slightly different , either with the secondary index if the 'accepted' does not need to be part of the primary key (as you did for your second schema), or a primary key like this :

```
PRIMARY KEY ((userId), accepted, ts_accepted)
```

I would definitely prefer the secondary index for the second table if possible because the accepted column has a low cardinality (2) and thus very well fitted for secondary indexes.

EDIT :

Also you used a timestamp in your primary key. Be aware that it may be a problem if you can have the same user creating two rows in this table. Because the timestamp does not guaranty unicity : what happens if the two rows are created the same millisecond ?

You should probably use a TimeUUID. This type very commonly used in Cassandra guaranty the unicity by combining a Timestamp and UUID.

Furthermore a timestamp in a primary key can create temporary hotspots in a Cassandra node, definitely beter to avoid.

Comment: So you are suggesting to have two tables, first with my schema A for queries 1 and 2, and second table with my schema B for query 3. But why can't I use just schema B for all 3 queries as primary key for accepted is not required.

Comment: Also If I use PRIMARY KEY ((userId), accepted, ts_accepted), I can't able to sort ts_accepted clustering column alone with order by, as I have to sort both 'accepted' and 'ts_accepted'. Sorting 'accepted' every time unwantedly brings performance issue.

Comment: Your first schema seemed to indicate that you needed the 'accepted' field in the Primary key. If you don't then for your particular use case I think that yes the indexed column is good (low cardinality, rare change), but it will still be slower than having the 'accepted' as a clustering column. Although for your case the difference should be minimal.